# printing calculated data in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm having trouble to find a way to print calculated data to template. I'll try to describe my situation best I can. I have a model named Dividend:

```
class Dividend(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField('pay date')
    amount = models.FloatField( validators=[MinValueValidator(0.001), MaxValueValidator(1000000000000000.0)])
    price = models.FloatField('price per share',
                              validators=[MinValueValidator(0.001), MaxValueValidator(1000000000000000.0)])
```

table of dividend data look like this:

```
Date    Dividend    Price
Sept. 26, 2013  $0.8    $24.75
June 26, 2013   $0.7    $24.74
March 26, 2013  $0.6    $23.59
Dec. 13, 2012   $0.4    $19.18
Sept. 26, 2012  $0.1    $20.66
```

I want to add percentage of how every dividend was raised(if it was). So something like this:

```
Date    Dividend    Price
Sept. 26, 2013  $0.8 (+12,5%)   $24.75
June 26, 2013   $0.7 (+14,28%)  $24.74
March 26, 2013  $0.6 (+50%)     $23.59
Dec. 13, 2012   $0.4 (+300%)    $19.18
Sept. 26, 2012  $0.1            $20.66
```

How do I do this? I have data in list, because I am adding some dividends that I don't want to be inserted into db. So I have a list of dividend objects.
Basically I would like to calculate that percentage change in view and add it as another parameter to each dividend.

```
for dividend in dividend_list:
    dividend.change = ...calculation...
```

and than simply add it in my template

```
{% for dividend in stock.dividend_set.all|order_by:"date" %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ dividend.date }}</td>
        <td>${{ dividend.amount }} ({{ dividend.change }}%)</td>
        <td>${{ dividend.price }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But I can't do it, because there is no model field change in Dividend. I store in new QueryDict, where key would be dividend.id and value percentage change. But I can not do query_dict[dividend.id] in template. So what is the best way to do this? I'm sorry for asking such a trivial question, but I don't know what to look for. Sorry for unsatisfactory title as well, I'll change it if I come up with something more descriptive after your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add arbitrary data to the instances in the view without needing them to be model fields.  This is fine:

```
for dividend in dividend_list:
    dividend.change = ...calculation...
```

Just make sure you pass `dividend_list` to your template context. Are you using class-based views or functional views? For class-based views, do this in `get_context_data` and add this to the return value. For functional views, put the modified `dividend` list (no longer a lazy evaluated queryset) into the dictionary argument:

```
    return render(template_name, {'dividend_list': dividend_list})
```

Then iterate over it in the template.

```
{% for dividend in dividend_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ dividend.date }}</td>
        <td>${{ dividend.amount }} ({{ dividend.change }}%)</td>
        <td>${{ dividend.price }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

You could also write a method on the Dividend model to do the calculation and then call it in the template loop, or even write a custom template tag to display the dividend.

Also, you really don't want to use `FloatField` to represent money.  Use `DecimalField` instead.

Comment: Thank! I'm sorry, I was using database data in template. Such a stupid mistake. Thanks for DecimalField advice as well, I realized too late and I'm lazy to rewrite it now. But since you pointed that out too, I will.